# View manipulation only works when one component is in view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, svg

I have an angular2 component which manipulates an SVG image based on data it receives from my real time API.

The exact same component is used in two views, the first is a list view, where there are lots of instances of the component.

The second is the detail component where there is only one instance of the component.

However, the component only works in the second view. The component look like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-line-overview',
  template: `<object id="img" data="assets/img/big_layout.svg" width="292" height="164" #svg></object>`
})
export class LineOverviewComponent {
  stations: string;
  @ViewChild('svg') svg: ElementRef;

  constructor(public socketService: SocketService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.socketService.getStations('api/getStations/' + this.line.name).subscribe(stns => {
        this.stations = stns.stations;
        this.load();
      })
  }

  load() {
      let svgDoc = this.svg.nativeElement.contentDocument;
      if (this.stations) {
        JSON.parse(this.stations).forEach(station => {
          station.element = svgDoc.getElementById(station.name);
          console.log(station)
          station.element.removeAttribute('class');
          if (station.status === 'running') {
            station.element.setAttribute('fill', 'lime');
          }
        })
      }
    }
}
```

In the list view, `station.element` is null throwing the error:

> inline template:19:24 caused by: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null

## Update:

see this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BNK6rbfBUAleXF6X9ckg?p=preview.

Comment: Hard to tell from here why `svgDoc.getElementById(station.name);` doesn't return an element.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer What other information would you need?

Comment: Probably a Plunker that allows to reproduce. It's not clear from your question why this line should find an element. What is `station.name`  when `load()` is called and does `svgDoc` really contain an element with that id?

Comment: I can be wrong but few days ago I faced similar issue. It seems like you can't manipulate DOM element at init. If you log `svgDoc` you'll see that it's undefined. You should try to put load() in `ngAfterViewInit()` function or any other life cycle hooks after ngOnInit https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Comment: @mickdev that seems to be the area causing the issue, as you suggested I added a `console.log(svgDoc)` to my `load()` function, but it isn't undefined, it returns `#document<html><head></head><body></body></html>`, but that is clearly from before the view is loaded, as a pose to my working view where the response looks like the svg element. However, I added an `ngAfterViewInit` event, and call `this.load()`, but still get the same result...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer If there are multiple instances of the svg element in the same view, will view encapsulation and ViewChild ensure that each component selects the correct svg?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer See the plunk I've attached, the same function is loaded after view init and on the button click, but it only works on the button click...